# What does ComSpec mean?

Tags: windows, command-line, ms-dos

Merely curious about the etymology of the Windows environment variable %COMSPEC%. I understand it (usually) points to cmd.exe.

The best I could find online is Command Specifier, which sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In regards to the etymology, it's self-referential. `%COMSPEC%` does stand for Command Specifier, and it "specifies" the command interpreter, which by default is `cmd.exe` in NT systems, and `COMMAND.COM` in DOS systems.

You can modify the variable to point to any secondary interpreter you want (this is a DOS example):

> `SET COMSPEC=C:\DOS\COMMAND.COM`
>
> `COMSPEC` specifies the secondary command interpreter.
>   This need not be `COMMAND.COM`.
>   One example of a different command interpreter is JP Software's 4DOS.COM.
>
> [Source](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/command.php)